# How to store a 5GB text file used by a web application for words search?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have 5 GB  txt file which includes 2,200,000 records of word and their number vectors. 
I want when user enters a query in txt box in my web application search for the word in text file and find consequent vector in the txt file. 
It is a constant txt file and i do not want to append any thing to it
Now is better I user this txt file or use a DB because it is a web application and response time is important for me.

Txt file is GLOVE (global vector for word representation).
Each record is something like this:

> the 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862
>   -0.00066023 -0.6566 0.27843 -0.14767 -0.55677 0.14658 -0.0095095 0.011658 0.10204 -0.12792 -0.8443 -0.12181 -0.016801 -0.33279 -0.1552 -0.23131 -0.19181 -1.8823 -0.76746 0.099051 -0.42125 -0.19526 4.0071 -0.18594 -0.52287 -0.31681 0.00059213 0.0074449 0.17778 -0.15897 0.012041 -0.054223 -0.29871 -0.15749 -0.34758 -0.045637 -0.44251 0.18785 0.0027849 -0.18411 -0.11514 -0.78581

Comment: I'd consider a dbms based solution. Hard to beat if properly designed .

Comment: Try both approaches and measure the time

Comment: (1) The post has no relevance to "big data". (2) I suggest showing a data sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a good fit for SQLite.
Create a table with 2 columns - 'word' and 'vector', import data, create an index on 'word' and you're done.

https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html

---

### Demo

#### generate file

Python

```
with open(r'c:\Temp\glove.txt','w') as f:
    for i in range(0,13000000):
        f.write('{}|{}\n'.format(1000001+i,'0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566 0.27843 -0.14767 -0.55677 0.14658 -0.0095095 0.011658 0.10204 -0.12792 -0.8443 -0.12181 -0.016801 -0.33279 -0.1552 -0.23131 -0.19181 -1.8823 -0.76746 0.099051 -0.42125 -0.19526 4.0071 -0.18594 -0.52287 -0.31681 0.00059213 0.0074449 0.17778 -0.15897 0.012041 -0.054223 -0.29871 -0.15749 -0.34758 -0.045637'))
```

#### Check file size

cmd

```
c:\Temp>dir glove.txt

 Directory of c:\Temp

12/04/2016  12:26 PM     5,204,000,001 glove.txt
               1 File(s)  5,204,000,001 bytes
```

#### Create SQLite database + Load data + Build index

```
c:\Temp>sqlite3 glove.db
SQLite version 3.15.1 2016-11-04 12:08:49
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table glove (word text,vector text);
sqlite> .import 'c:\Temp\glove.txt' glove
sqlite> create unique index glove_un_word on glove(word);
```

---

#### Search

```
sqlite> .timer on
sqlite> select vector from glove where word = '7654321';
0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566 0.27843 -0.14767 -0.55677 0.14658 -0.0095095 0.011658 0.10204 -0.12792 -0.8443 -0.12181 -0.016801 -0.33279
0059213 0.0074449 0.17778 -0.15897 0.012041 -0.054223 -0.29871 -0.15749 -0.34758 -0.045637
Run Time: real 0.004 user 0.000000 sys 0.000000
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 2):

Both are file based, but a database organizes your data (indexes, etc...) , caches your queries and procedures, enforces security, rules and data integrity. This make it faster to query the data you want. You can also back-up data with multiple options and schedules. You can archive conditionally based on date constraints. All these can be hard to do with a flat file.

You need to consider your particular case and check the pros and cons of every approach.

Consider that your problem might expand in the future, if you don't design your solution properly you might be dependent of the file-approach and consume more time trying to convert to the second approach. So design wisely so that shifting the approach is easy.

Answer (score 1):

txt file is big enough and if you do not use a db, each time you will load txt file into memory and do full text search or at the beginning you will cache the txt file and do the full text search from cached data. You should avoid from loading txt file into memory each time. Instead of that, if you do not want to use a db, when your application starts, you may load txt file into memory and then load the txt file data into an indexed component like Dictionary in C#. However, because the data is so big, the row count may be so big too and for that reason working from memory may slow down you.

I think the best solution would be using a db and an indexed table.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a key/value based NoSQL solution like Azure Table Storage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables). They excel in getting data based fast on the key. They scale very well as well.

For Azure Table Storage your Partition Key could be the first character of the word and the Row Key could be the whole word. The value would then be the vector. In your case you can then create a query based on the partition and row key and that is blazing fast (See https://www.troyhunt.com/working-with-154-million-records-on/ , section "A serious problem – it’s too damn fast")

There are other alternatives to azure table storage like Redis or MemCacheDb.